# ant - JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

Tags: java, ant

I have installed java with the command sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk and set the java home and path.But when I am trying to use ant I

```
JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_60/bin/java
```

Please help me how to resolve this error.

```
which java   ----> /usr/bin/java
java -version ---->java version "1.6.0_31"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3) (6b31-1.13.3-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

echo $JAVA_HOME  ----->  /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_60
```

Comment: I think, it should JDK but not just JRE.

Comment: So, do you have an executable `/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_60/bin/java` or not? Post `ls` or something.

Comment: Run `update-java-alternatives -l` and then `update-java-alternatives -s` with the openjdk-7-jdk you installed.

Comment: usr$ ls --> bin  games  include  lib  local  sbin  share  src

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem than you. Try using Oracle jdk instead openjdk

To change OpenJdk by Oracle JDK you can do (you have to download oracle jdk first):

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_37/bin/java" 1
```

Here you have a detailed explanation:

http://hendrelouw73.wordpress.com/2012/11/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-6-0-37-on-ubuntu-12-04-linux/

You can set your environment by doing:

```
vi /etc/environment
```

in my case I did:

```
PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/"
```

and it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Ant requires JDK and you have installed JRE. So ant is throwing such an error.

So, just **Uninstall JRE** and then **install JDK**, this will solve your error.